# Get path helper from url, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know if there is a way to get the `path helper` from an `url` into a `Controller` something like:

```
def url_to_path(url)
       ########## CODE
end

url_to_path('/') #### root_path
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you wanting a function that will return a path, given a url? A path is a subset of a url, so this can be accomplished with a simple regex-based function.

Comment: are you wanting to get a path helper from the current url? or some randome url? where is this url coming from?

Comment: @Dogweather How? Can you explain more the answer

Comment: @RichardJordan Any Url

Comment: The path is the part of the url after the hostname...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information on routes as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("/", { :method => :get })
```

This will give you the controller, action and params.  From that you can build the path names easily, if that's what you want.

If you want a list of all the named_routes helpers:

```
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers
```